# How To Create PHP Array to JSON Array using json_encode();

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've encoded an Array I've made using the inbuilt json_encode(); function. I need it in the format of an Array of Arrays like so:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "Info": "A",
      "hasil": "AA"
    },
    {
      "Info": "B",
      "hasil": "BB"
    },
    {
      "Info": "C",
      "hasil": "CC"
    },
    {
      "Info": "D",
      "hasil": "DD"
    },
    {
      "Info": "F",
      "hasil": "FF"
    },
    {
      "Info": "G",
      "hasil": "GG"
    },
    {
      "Info": "H",
      "hasil": "HH"
    },
    {
      "Info": "I",
      "hasil": "II"
    },
    {
      "Info": "J",
      "hasil": "JJ"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need it is returning as:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": 
    {
      "Info": "A",
      "hasil": "AA"
    },
    {
      "Info": "B",
      "hasil": "BB"
    },
    {
      "Info": "C",
      "hasil": "CC"
    },
    {
      "Info": "D",
      "hasil": "DD"
    },
    {
      "Info": "F",
      "hasil": "FF"
    },
    {
      "Info": "G",
      "hasil": "GG"
    },
    {
      "Info": "H",
      "hasil": "HH"
    },
    {
      "Info": "I",
      "hasil": "II"
    },
    {
      "Info": "J",
      "hasil": "JJ"
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have actually tried.

Comment: Why do you want some invalid, grotesque version of JSON instead of actual JSON? You presumably want to transport data from PHP to JavaScript; why deliver something that JSON.parse() can't parse?

Comment: What s wrong with an Object that contains a Property called `data` which is an array of other Objects. Thats perfect for using in Javascript. Which afterall is the point of JSON

Answer (score 2):

Your example of what you want it to look like is not valid JSON. It needs to be outputted like how you see it currently being outputted. You have multiple items under `data` and as such they need to be in an array. Think of JSON like it's a normal variable you have. You can't store a list of items like that without it being an array.

Comment: how to make it like that

Comment: `json_encode` will not make it like that for you as it is not valid JSON and it will not be usable JSON.